# How to implement drag and drop using jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

What is difference between :

```
<img src="${request.contextPath}/ActionImagePath?Key='+imageListInJason[key].thumbKey+'"><br>
```

and

```
<div  style="background:url(${request.contextPath}/ActionImagePath?Key='+imageListInJason[key].thumbKey+')">
```

Second case helps in IE8 while doing drag and drop to get the droppable property.

But I want to know what does it make any supporting difference to IE8 while `using <div style="background:url('Any action Path')">`

Comment: I don't think jQuery is the correct tag since there is no jQuery in your examples. A `$` doesn't is not implicit for jQuery. IF there is some JavaScript code, you should post it was well.

Comment: @ DrColossosAs : You are right.
But i have done with the drag and drop functionality in my code.So if i paste all the js code then it will create the complexity to understand the problem domain. i just want to know that while dropping the element i require to get some property from the droppable area, previously it was creating the problem. but when i have added the <div style="background:url('Any action Path')"> it works fine. in place of <img src="Any action path"/>.Thanks in advance.